# Is there a way to create our own stackoverflow sub-sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For example a lot of my friends all study CS at different schools and we currently use a Facebook group where we all ask and answer each others questions, but obviously the layout isn't ideal and our own page. 
 e.g. myfriendgroup.stackoverflow.com, would be much better.

If this isn't currently available - do you guys think it would be a good idea? Is it something you'd like to see implemented? I could see it being profitable for the site too, they could sell personalized pages to universities and such.

**Edit:** nevermind, [got an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83591/how-to-run-a-private-stack-exchange-like-site).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not available, nor a good idea.

Stack Overflow is deliberately *not* a social network, and focusing on people rather than content would detract from its primary mission.

Note that if you *do* focus on questions and answers posted by your friends, you run the risk of running afoul of voting ring fraud; make sure that you vote on posts not because they were created by someone you know, but because you feel the content is great (or bad, in which case you downvote).

If you were looking to create a private Q&A site, you can always install one of the [many clones, locally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) and use that. Stack Exchange *does* appear to be [experimenting with specialty sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228721/what-is-cs50-and-why-cant-i-access-it) for universities, but the company has not yet made anything public about these sites yet.

Comment: I'm not asking to create a social network, just create smaller versions of the site with the same tools and layout. In the same way that we have Q&A sites for everything from personal fitness to aviation we could also have sites for a particular university that professors can tell their students to go on when stuck.

E.g. my uni currently uses a forum and to say it's clunky and outdated is an understatement.

Comment: Thanks for the clones, that's the kind of thing I was looking for :)

Comment: @JmJ: right; your use of a network of friends, and the term 'Stack Overflow sub-site' really suggested that you wanted a sort of social networking group on Stack Overflow instead of a dedicated subject-specific site.

Comment: I don't see why you'd want to deliberately limit your pool of answers to those written by a handful of people. Just use SE normally...?